# Database Design - Foreign Key and Primary Key relationships across 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, primary-key

As a personal project to myself, I am trying to redesign one of our existing Access database tools at work into VB.net. This is including a database redesign from scratch as the current one is an absolute mess.

Here is the database as it stands at the moment with my current re-design in SQL Server:

[image]

Now to make the relationships clear:

On the `Client` table, `Client_ID` is the primary key. This has a relationship to `Contracts.Client_ID` as its foreign key. This also has a relationship to `Sites.Client_ID` as its foreign key.

On the `Sites` table, `Site_ID` is the primary key. This has a relationship to `Contracts.Site_ID` as its foreign key.

Each primary key in every table auto-increments by one on each record creation.

The idea here is a simple Client/Site/Contract structure. For example, Client: Microsoft, Site: Reading Head Office, Contracts (any type of contract that could apply to either the company as whole or an individual site).

You can't have a site without a client. You should be able to link a contract to a client or a site. At present I have allowed Nulls for both `Site_ID` and `Client_ID` in contracts to facilitate this as I can't find any way to ensure at least one is filled in.

Does this design look reasonable and follow best practice? I've tried to follow best practice as per a number of different suggestions found across the web, namingly separating tables for different types of data. Any input would be gratefully received

Comment: If the site has a client id, and the contract has a site id, the contract does not need a client id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you check out [creating and altering CHECK constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179491%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). a simple condition of (Client_ID IS NOT NULL OR Site_ID IS NOT NULL)

As a side note, the structure should work for the business rules. Can a Client have a contract with without a site to work at or on? Does this make sense? If so, then go with what you have, if not, I'd suggest requiring site information for contracts (where will you be sending the invoice?), and therefore you can probably eliminate client_id from contracts.

Given that simple is the case here, I won't dive into other considerations like, should a phone number be attached to sites, or contacts? I would say contacts as the number for the renewal person is likely very different than the one for whom the contract was written.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had no idea about check constraints so that is exceptionally helpful. Yes, a client can have a contract without linking it to a site.

To demonstrate with a real life example, we're an MSP. Say we have a contract with a client called Acme Ltd, they have 5 sites, Acme London, Acme Paris etc etc. Acme Ltd have Office 365 for all their employees. That type of contract should link to the client and not the site as it encompasses all sites. That's made me realise though that I may need to add some more column into the clients table. You've been a great help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

**Clients**

ClientID PK, Name

only the attributes specific to a client

**Client_Contracts**

ClientID FK [Clients(ClientID)],  ContractID FK (Contrats[ContractID])

**Contratcs**

ContractID(PK), StartDate, EndDate , SiteID FK (Sites [SiteID])

Only the attributes that a contract must have.

**Sites**

SiteID PK, all the columns for a site.

Comment: What are the benefits in separating out the contract references to their own table? Would it then not follow to make a Site_Contracts too? Genuinely intrigued, please don't think I am saying you are wrong, I just am looking to learn the reasons behind it :)

Comment: With your current design if you have two clients on same site you will end up repeating all the information in Sites tables only to add another client for that site. Which violates the rules of database normalization. Your goal should be to reduce the data redundancy in an OLTP application database.

Comment: I see, I didn't consider that as there would never be two clients on one site. The real dataset behind this would likely only have one site per client, but for a few they have say 5 sites across the UK, which would fall under the same client; but there would never be two clients with one site. Sorry if I made that confusing!

Comment: I am not aware of your business requirements but if you think a contract can span over multiple sites yes then you should also have a Contract_Sites Table. and further normalize you database.